# Errors on building haddock documentation with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I'm currently developing [small application](https://github.com/m0nhawk/XComposeChecker) on Haskell. I have all documented and `main` too. But `cabal haddock --executables` show errors:

```
Running Haddock for XComposeChecker-0.1...
Preprocessing executables for XComposeChecker-0.1...
Warning: The documentation for the following packages are not installed. No
links will be generated to these packages: rts-1.0
haddock coverage for ./XComposeChecker.hs:    8/13  62%
Warning: Couldn't find TyThing for exported Main.main: main:Main.main; not documenting.
haddock coverage for dist/build/tmp3599/./Main.hs:     1/2  50%
Warning: Main: could not find link destinations for:
    Main.main
Documentation created: dist/doc/html/XComposeChecker/checker/index.html
```

And `Main.hs` itself:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath

import XComposeChecker

-- | Main
main = do
         homedir <- getHomeDirectory
         result <- parseFromFile parseXComposeFile (joinPath [homedir, ".XCompose"])
         print result
```

Why `haddock` can't find documentation for `main`?

Using `ghc-7.0.4`, `cabal-1.10.2.0` and `haddock-2.9.2` on `Fedora 17`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haddock documentation has to be attached to type signatures. Try this:

```
-- | Main
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print 3
```

**Addition:** It's also necessary to add:

```
module Main(main) where
```

in the beginning of the `Main.hs`, this allows `haddock` to find and document the `main` function.

Comment: I believe that nowadays you can get away without putting down the type signature.